# Easy Probability Distribution Problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-variables

Suppose we randomly draw 20 winning numbers out of 70 numbers. Let $X_m$ be the number of winning numbers that we got when choosing $m$ numbers.

Determine the distribution of $X_m$, i.e. $P(X_m = k)$ for $k=0,1,...,m$.

Ok please let me know if I'm doing this right:

$k=0:$ Here we want to find the probability of getting $0$ winning numbers when randomly picking $m$ numbers. This should be $$P(X_m = 0) = \frac{50}{70} \cdot \frac{49}{69} \cdot ... \cdot \frac{50-m+1}{70-m+1}$$

$k=1:$ Here we get one winning number. Is this the following?
$$P(X_m = 1) = \frac{20 \cdot {m \choose 1}}{70} \cdot \frac{50}{69} \cdot \frac{49}{68} \cdot ... \cdot \frac{50-m+2}{50-m+1}$$

$k=2:$ And is this right?
$$P(X_m = 2) = \frac{20 \cdot 19 \cdot {m \choose 2} \cdot 50 \cdot 49 \cdot ... \cdot 50-m+3}{70 \cdot 69 \cdot ... \cdot (70-m+1)}$$

Please let me know if I'm doing this right, and if not, what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4):

So far so good.

You have $$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(X_m=0) &= \frac{{50\choose m}{}}{70\choose m}
\\[1ex]
\mathsf P(X_m=1) &= \frac{{20\choose 1}{50\choose m-1}}{70\choose m}
\\[1ex]
\mathsf P(X_m=2) &= \frac{{20\choose 2}{50\choose m-2}}{70\choose m}
\end{align}$$

Do you see enough of a pattern to generalize to any $\mathsf P(X_m=k)$?

Answer (score 3):

The distribution of $X_m$ is [Hypergeometric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) with parameters

- $N=70$, the population size,
- $K=m$, successes in the population, (these are the numbers that we have choosed)
- $n=20$, the sample size.

Hence $$P(X_m=k)=\frac{\dbinom{m}{k}\dbinom{N-m}{n-k}}{\dbinom{N}{n}}$$ for $k\, \in \left\{\max{(0,\, 20+m-70)},\, \dots,\, \min{(m,\, 20 )}\right\}$

Comment: $m$ is the sample size. $K=20$ is the successes in the population.

Comment: @GrahamKemp. I think that it works also as I have it. If I choose m numbers then I put a mark on them and they are the successes in the population. After that $20$ are sampled in random.